# An incomprehensible code is passed instead of the Id

Tags: xamarin

When I send a request to the server, an unknown code is sent instead of the id:

> /api/community/cedc3591-f9ed-4e89-bceb-85b639323bb9/join

I checked, the method for uploading communities correctly adds the id to the model. I can't determine what the problem is. Maybe I'm incorrectly passing the Id into my methods, I've tried a lot of things, but nothing helps.

Here's my view:

```
<ListView x:Name="CommunitiesListView" RowHeight="150">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame HasShadow="True" Margin="10" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="15">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Padding="10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="16" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Slogan}" FontSize="14" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Creator.Name, StringFormat='Создатель: {0}'}" FontSize="14" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding MembersCount, StringFormat='Участников: {0}'}" FontSize="14" />
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                            <Button Text="Вступить"
                                Clicked="JoinCommunityAsync"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                                BackgroundColor="#81b745"
                                TextColor="White"
                                CornerRadius="5"
                                Margin="0,20,5,0" />

                            <Button Text="Выйти"
                                Clicked="LeaveCommunityAsync"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                                BackgroundColor="#b74545"
                                TextColor="White"
                                CornerRadius="5"
                                Margin="0,20,0,0" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

My methods:

```
private async void JoinCommunityAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string accessToken = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("AccessToken");

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            string apiUrl = $"http://192.168.0.14:8000/api/community/{Id}/join";
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, null);
            Console.WriteLine($"Sending request to: {apiUrl}");

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Успех", "Вы вступили в сообщество", "ОК");
            }
            else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Ошибка", "Вы уже находитесь в данном сообществе", "ОК");
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Ошибка", "Произошла ошибка при вступлении в сообщество", "ОК");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Ошибка", ex.Message, "OK");
    }
}

private async void LeaveCommunityAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string accessToken = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("AccessToken");

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            string apiUrl = $"http://192.168.0.14:8000/api/community/{Id}/leave";
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, null);

            Console.WriteLine($"Sending request to: {apiUrl}");
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Успех", "Вы вышли с сообщества", "ОК");
            }
            else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Ошибка", "Вы не находитесь в данном сообществе", "ОК");
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Ошибка", "Произошла ошибка при выходе из сообщества", "ОК");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Ошибка", ex.Message, "OK");
    }
}
```

My model:

```
public class CommunityModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: that "incomprehesible code" appears to be a GUID. You are attempting to pass the ID value in `CommandParameter`, but you are using an event handler, not a command.  You can't pass arguments with event handlers.